# Problem in storing into ms-access as unicode

Tags: jsp, unicode

I have one JSP page which has one text field. I'm entering some kannada characters. I'm able to encode it in UTF-8 format and I'm passing this value to another JSP.

In an alert box, I'm getting the correct characters, but when I store into MS-access by using JDBC-ODBC driver, the values are stored as question marks (`?`) and while fetching, it also displays question marks in JSP.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Should that be "katakana"?  Are these Japanese characters?

Comment: It's an Indian language and phonetic alphabet. If you have the fonts, it looks like this: ಅಆಇಈಉಊ

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259477) from Microsoft leads me to believe that there's a problem with ODBC drivers and Unicode.  But I'm not 100% certain.

I'd try either switching databases or ODBC drivers if the article turned out to be true.  Is Access a requirement?

Comment: +1 on changing databases, Access should never be connected to a web app. There are much better free alternatives as well as SQL Server.